# Добавление элементов в Json массив с помощью Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5, c++11

Мне нужно добавить элементы к массиву в Json файле:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>


int main()
{
    QJsonDocument document {};

    QJsonObject object {document.object()};

    object.insert("array", QJsonArray{"first element"});

    QJsonArray arr_correct = object["array"].toArray(); // отрабатывает нормально
    arr_correct.append("second element");
    object["array"] = arr_correct;

    QJsonArray arr_uncorrect {object["array"].toArray()}; // добавляет не туда
    arr_uncorrect.append("third element");
    object["array"] = arr_uncorrect;

    document.setObject(object);
    qDebug() << qPrintable(document.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented));

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
{
    "array": [
        [
            "first element",
            "second element"
        ],
        "third element"
    ]
}
```

Вопрос такой, почему объявление переменной QJsonArray через uniform инициализацию интерпретирует QJsonValue, как массив из одно элемента, а через присваивание все хорошо?

Собираю с помощью MinGW 7.3.0, Qt 5.12.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qt 5.12.3 microsoft visual studio 2015

```
{
    "array": [
        "first element",
        "second element",
        "third element"
    ]
}
```

Ваше создание кстати совсем какое-то неправильное,

```
{
    "array": [
        [
            "first element",
            "second element"
        ],
        "third element"
    ]
}
```

в array у вас создается доп массив из двух элементов, а вот third element как раз таки попадает в array.

P.S. а можете поменять местами юниформ-инициализацию и через присваивание, если будет картинка наоборот, то видимо в 12.5 завезли баг

Comment: Это баг компилятора. GCC использует не правильный конструктор. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-79780

Comment: @stade, дополните Ваш вопрос данной информацией.